# how to check if a value is 1 and then change it to 0

Tags: android, sql

how do i check if a value is `1.000000` in my column(that is called trashed numeric(18, 6)that are in fileitem table) then i update and if it is `1.000000` then i wan't to change it to `0.000000`

my statement for updateing is

```
String query ="Update PS set ShelfNumber =' "+text2+ " ' from [file].[ItemPart] PS "+ " join [file].[Item] P on P.id = PS.id "+ " where P.ItemNumber = '"+text1 + "'";
                        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
                        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

not sure if i have to make it as a stored procedure for being able to do it

Comment: You're creating a prepared statement, but you're constructing your query via string concatenation...  Please do some research into using parameterized queries via prepared statements.  Your query is wide open to SQL Injection.

Comment: i just have this for a test all that stuff and optimization will be done on realase

Comment: There is no excuse for string concatenated SQL - not even for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect an `update` to look something like this:

```
update t
    set trashed = 0
    where trashed = 1;
```

Comment: i get this when i try
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_Item_ToralQuantity". The conflict occurred in database "ISTABLocalDB", table "file.Item".

Comment: @KewinBjörkNielsen . . . As the error suggests, this update violates a `check` constraint.  You might want to ask another question, and include the  definition of the table, along with the check constraint.

Comment: yeah seems like in my constraint i also need to change some other values before i can change trashed